# How to get hard volume key event in J2ME LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midp

I am having a media player application built using LWUIT. My problem is that I am unable to increase/decrease the volume of the media player when the user presses any volume hardware key of the device. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an app with a plain `Canvas` and run it on your device.  On the canvas's [`keyPressed`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#keyPressed%28int%29) function, print the results out to the screen.  I suspect nothing will happen when you press the volume keys, in which case you have no way of doing anything when these keys are pressed.

Comment: Thanks funkybro for your reply. I have checked that no events are caught when we press volume keys. In such a case, we have no other way to rectify it.

Answer (score 2):

For some devices you just don't get an event and for others you will get wildly differing values as funkybro has stated. You can do the same experiment with a LWUIT application (no need for canvas).

Android does expose volume keys but I would recommend avoiding them and letting it handle its own volume since its such a complicated subject on Android. The RIM implementation in LWUIT has a static listener which you can bind to volume key events but this will only work on RIM devices.

Comment: Thanks shai for your response. As you stated, can i get a list of devices which support these events along with those values because i am developing only for some specific phones. May be i can identify the family of devices which support these events, or i can handle them differently for all using preprocessors. I am able to map volume keys for blackberry using RIM's keylistener, but am unable to find something similar for J2ME devices.

Comment: We don't maintain such a list since the effort required would be impractical to maintain such a list.